# Cocos2d with view controller

Tags: uikit, cocos2d-iphone

I am new in cocos2d game and want to develop a game related to slingshot like angry birds.
I have a single view based application and I want to use slingshot logic in my view based app like in angry birds.

Can anyone please help me how I can do that?

How I can use uikit and cocos 2d together?

Comment: Why do want to use UIKit? Do you even know what UIKit is?

Comment: yes i know that but i want to add cocos in my single view based app

Answer (score 0):

By default, any cocos2d app begins from creating main view controller, then creating OpenGL view. Just create any cocos project from templates and you will see it. Any cocos2d app is one-view app. It's view is OpenGL view.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_1._install_test

install xcode templates as described here, then just create simple application from cocos2d template, there you can find an example of creation simple cocos2d app

Comment: Yes, then if you want to you can add UIKit views as children to that EAGLView. Bear in mind they'll all appear above anything you do in Cocos2D.

Comment: can u please tell me how to create EAGLView and openGL view using viewcontroller